# Good behavior of Java Server built using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have this piece of server code:

```
Socket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
socket = serverSocket.accept();socket = serverSocket.accept();
byte buf[] = new byte[2];
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
int r;
while ((r = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    builder.append(new String(buf, 0, r));
}
socket.getOutputStream().write(....
```

My client only connects to the server, sends bytes through the outputstream and expects some kind of answer from the server.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
socket.getOutputStream().write("some string".getBytes());
// then manipulating with input stream
```

The problem is the fact that integer r is never -1, because it becomes -1 only when connection is closed (as I understood). Because of that, my server hangs on "is.read(buf)" expecting client to send something else, while client has finished sending data and already expecting server to send the response.

My question: how does a server know that a client has finished sending its data? What is the appropriate byte buffer size? If I expect large data to be transfered through network, how do I know how many times "is.read(buf)" has to be called? What is the correct server behavior in this case?

UPD: I need them to communicate through the sockets like in chat application. So I cannot close Outputstream of the client socket. Though I tried to close outputstream after writing into it, that led to java.net.SocketException saying that socket is closed.

Comment: Close the client output when you are finished.  Java sockets (and TCP/IP) have independent IO streams.  You can close one half of the stream while the other remains open.

Comment: @markspace, I have tried this outputStream.close(); But when I tried to read something from InputStream, it gave me an exception saying that Socket is closed. Also I need client and server to communicate like in a chat application, so I should keep the streams open.

Comment: With the exception of the remote side closing its end of the socket connection, TCP has no concept of indicating if the remote side has exhausted everything it wants to send.  As such, you'll need to build your own header and message format into your socket stream to indicate "how many more bytes to follow".  Does that make sense?

Comment: @selbie Thank you, now it is clear